# how to include python modules in linux?

Tags: python, linux, module, xgoogle

I found this xgoogle python modules http://github.com/pkrumins/xgoogle, very interesting. How exactly should i include or install these files in linux??

if i want to do something like this using xgoogle python module?

```
>>from xgoogle.search import GoogleSearch
```

I know that we can use from, import to use modules, but to include an external module, what should  i do? Should i need to install module or what?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could either do the usual install dance:

```
python setup.py install
```

or simply include the files in a known directory and include that directory in the PYTHONPATH:

```
$ export PYTHONPATH=/contains/modules:$PYTHONPATH
```

Here's a detailed documentation on Installing Python Modules: http://docs.python.org/install/

Comment: In the directory of xgoogle, there is no install file, see the contents below `abhilash@abhilash:~/python_resources/xgoogle/xgoogle$ ls
BeautifulSoup.py   browser.py   googlesets.py  search.py          translate.py
BeautifulSoup.pyc  browser.pyc  __init__.py    sponsoredlinks.py
`

Comment: what about one directory level above? There should be a `setup.py` file.

Answer (score 0):

You can install it with other python libraries / modules, or just put it in the same repository than your project.