# Add Python script so can be imported in another Python script

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

So I know in windows you can just add the file to the Lib folder and then just add **import filename** to the python script.

Is it possible to do this on Ubuntu in anyway as I need to import this file to make a project work. [Link to file need to access](https://github.com/ianozsvald/ark-tweet-nlp-python/blob/master/CMUTweetTagger.py)

Comment: just put it in the same folder as well, or anywhere in you classpath

Comment: So add to the pythonpath variable or classpath. Sorry bit of linux newbie

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to include python modules in linux?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3839334/how-to-include-python-modules-in-linux)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I toured the github repo for a bit, 
it should be possible to simply copy `CMUTweetTagger.py` to your folder where `yourapp.py` is located (same level) then

```
import CMUTweetTagger

CMUTweetTagger.runtagger_parse(...)
```

Alternatively, since `ark-tweet-nlp-python` is a package (has got `__init__.py` in it)

You can copy the whole `ark-tweet-nlp-python` folder into e.g. `ark_tweet_nlp_python` folder (again same level as your script), e.g. by cloning it

Git clone:

```
git clone https://github.com/ianozsvald/ark-tweet-nlp-python ark_tweet_nlp_python
```

Use it as a module:

```
from ark_tweet_nlp_python import CMUTweetTagger
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

```
import sys
print sys.path
sys.path.append('/path/to/lib/dir')
import mylib
```

Also, if the python script you are trying to import is in a directory, you need to make sure that you have an **init**.py file in that folder.  It can be empty (`touch /path/to/lib/dir/__init__.py`) before an import will work.  You can `ls /path/to/lib/dir` to see if there is an **init**.py file.